# JSON doesn't load using Panini

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Zurb Foundation for Emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails) and I'm looking to create a really simple multi-language email export system where I have this `data/lang.json`:

```
{
  "en": {
        "hello": "hello",
        "welcome": "Welcome to my website"
  },
  "fr": {
          "hello": "Bonjour",
          "other": "Bienvenue sur mon site web"
  }
}
```

.. and based on the `lang` attribute of `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">`

I need to use the corresponding object from the JSON.

Zurb uses Panini and Handlebars so I'm doing this to get started:

```
{{lang.en.hello}}
```

.. but nothing shows up on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there the src/data directory is missing in the gulpfile.babel.js around line 50.

```
.pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages',
      layouts: 'src/layouts',
      partials: 'src/partials',
      helpers: 'src/helpers',
      data: 'src/data'
```

If you want the browser reload function to work you should also add a watch expression with the others (around ln:106):

```
gulp.watch('src/data/**/*.json').on('change', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, inline, browser.reload));
```

See also https://github.com/zurb/panini

Good luck!